# Not able to import pandas on command line in Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, command-line, anaconda

[command line prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU9Tv.png)  [Powershell command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au11g.png) I am trying to import pandas lib from command line and Powershell prompt in Anaconda (version 2.1.4 under Windows 10 Home) but it is giving error, though it is working fine in Spyder, Jupyter and PyCharm in Anaconda. It is not working on normal windows command prompt also.

When I tried to re-install pandas using command "pip install pandas", it gives the message that the same has already been installed. I tried adding environmental variables but that also didn't work. A screenshots of the same are enclosed. The python version I am using is 3.10.4

I will be grateful if someone can help to sort out this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you provide exact error messages it is almost impossible for other people to help you.

Comment: Hey Daniel, I have attached 2 screenshots of the error messages in my original post. Please refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot you provided, I think your input command caused you to enter the python environment on your local computer, not the virtual environment created by Anaconda.

Try typing "python" as the command to enter the interpreter instead of "python3".